# Notification when function is registered on e.g. $(document).ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

is there a way to be notified when a function is registered via the jQuery `$(document)ready()` functionality and get a reference to that?

**The background:**
Im using a parent theme on a wordpress site, which uses ajax page transitions and document ready is only called on the first load. Now i want a reference to each function previously registered to call them again if my page changes.

**The goal:** is to restore the functionality of `$(document).ready()` as not only me, but many other plugins out there are using it and i obviously dont want to rewrite them all.
Yes, i could call MY registered function with no efford but this feels kind of lackluster while destroying the underlying functionality. By the way: it is the parent themes transitions, so overriding this wouldn't be the best solution either.

What i want is to provide an addition, that intercepts every registration and calls the registered functions again manually after the transition. Is that a good idea?
(notice calling ready() manually doesn't work if it was called already automatically on the initial page load)

Comment: "*If there is a better approach please tell me!*". Probably listening gloval AJAX events would be simpler?

Comment: Use $.ajax done/always callback to call your method.

Comment: Which method are you using to perform these transitions ? It should exist a "end-of-function" callback you could use to know when the process is complete.

Comment: add some simple code to help you better.

Comment: what do you mean "Register a function"?

Comment: i mean if i have $(document).ready(function(){}); this function is registered to be called when, well the document is ready ;)

Comment: @dfsq yes but i need the registered functinons to call them then as i'm not the only one using document ready...

Answer (score 0):

why dont you wrap them all in a onPageChanged function and call that on document ready, and in the success handler from ajax calls

Comment: i added more information to my question to clarify my intentions. Your solution would work, if my plugin would be the only one but many plugins rely on the functionality